# Univocity Parsers: Is there a way to select a col, and if it doesn't exist in the file, have the parser parse the col name and values in it as "null"?

Tags: java, csv, parsing

Is there a way to select a column, and if it doesn't exist in the .csv file, then have the parser parse the column name and any values in it as "null" or "empty"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should work just fine:

```
@Test
public void fieldSelectionTest() throws Exception {
    CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
    settings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);
    settings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");
    settings.setNullValue("N/A"); //null value here

    settings.selectFields("Year", "???");

    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);

    String input = "" +
            "Year,Header1,Header2\n" +
            "2000,foo,bar\n" +
            "2016,blah,etc\n";

    for (String[] row : parser.parseAll(new StringReader(input))) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }
}
```

Will print:

```
[2000, N/A]
[2016, N/A]
```

Hope this helps